# Access user-created Google Maps via API?

Tags: google-maps, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to access data users have added to "open collaboration" Google maps via API?

I am building a service that involves users inputting travel plans. I want to make my service backwards-compatible for users who already use Google Maps (in open collaboration mode, where one user creates a map that other users can add markers to). If I have users authenticate with Google via oauth, is it possible to access these user-created markers in order to import them to my service?